# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.spire.xls.packages.sprRFA (in module spire.xls.free) cannot access class

Tags: java, excel, javafx

I am getting an exception and I can't find the reason of it. The exception I get is :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.spire.xls.packages.sprRFA (in module spire.xls.free) cannot access class sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.action to module spire.xls.free

```
@FXML
public void OnCreateFile(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    String po1 = Word.getText();
    String[] ss1 = po1.split(" ");
    String po2 = Output.getText();
    String[] ss2 = po2.split(" ");


    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

    Worksheet sheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
    sheet.insertArray(ss1, 0, 0, true);
    sheet.insertArray(ss2, 0, 1, true);

    workbook.saveToFile("dictionary.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2016);
}
```

Any help? Also would like to know is there any other way to export array in Excel document using Java.

Comment: Please have a look at [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). This is the library we are using to create excel documents

Comment: The error is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access)

Comment: Also similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225921/olp-cli-error-java-base-does-not-export-sun-security-util-to-unnamed-module-und).  You can contact the maintainers of the spire library and ask them to fix it to work with recent Java versions in a modular runtime environment.  In the meantime, the command line switches demonstrated in the related questions might allow you to get the application to execute.

Comment: POI is an alternative library, if you choose to look into using it there is [some discussion about doing so in a JavaFX application in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284441/troubleshooting-with-export-tableview-to-excel-javafx/70284638#70284638), though it is not a complete tutorial on integrating POI into a JavaFX application.

Comment: A simpler alternative might be to export to a CSV file rather than a spreadsheet. Excel can easily read CSV files.  If you choose to do this, you could do this without an external library, but it would probably be best to find a good Java CSV library and use that.

Comment: perhaps you can use this --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: @JawadElFou I'm guessing that should read  `--add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=spire.xls.free` because that is the name of the module being used, it is not an unnamed module.  I didn't try this to verify it would work, likely it would from the previously linked answers.

Comment: @jewelsea you are most probably right.

Comment: I set the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environmental variable to `--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=spire.office.free` and it still doesn't work with OpenJDK11. The only solution was to use `bellsoft-jre11.0.22` JRE and now the option works.

Answer (score -1):

This thread might be of help:https://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/illegal-access-error-when-instantiating-workbook-t10921.html